# How to fill a combo box with Types

Tags: c#, types, combobox, enums

I'm creating an editor for my game as a windows forms project in C#.
There are many cases where I would want to fill a combo box with all of the possible derived types of parent class. For example, you are adding an item, so you select from a list "weapon, armour, ammo, consumable, currency, etc." (these are all classes that are derived from "item")

At the moment, I manually define an enum with one member for each Type in the list, and then use the enum to fill out the options in the combo box. I then need two dictionaries: one to go from the enum to the Type, and one to go from a Type to an enum. In this way I can refresh the combo box to show the Type of an item when it is selected, and I can replace an item with a newly instantiated item when the combo box accepts user input.

This all works fine, it just seems like terrible code to manually type out an enum an two dictionaries, just to display and select from a list of things that already exist in the code base.

How can I do this better?

Comment: This seems like a perfect situation for reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use reflection to get all class types with the base type of `Item` and populate the `ComboBox` with that data; then tell it which property of `Type` to display to the user (probably `Name`).

```
foreach (var item in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                             .Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(Item)))
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
}

comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```